# Calculating standard errors from accuracy results of a classifier?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, standard-error

The below code prints the accuracy scores over 10 folds like below

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits, load_iris, load_breast_cancer, load_wine
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, zero_one_loss, confusion_matrix
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


z = pd.read_csv('/home/user/datasets/iris_dataset.csv', header=0)

X = z.iloc[:, :-1]
y = z.iloc[:, -1:]

X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)

# Performing standard scaling
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)

# Defining the SVM with 'rbf' kernel
svc = SVC(kernel='rbf',random_state=50)

#X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.10, shuffle=True)

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)
acc_score = []
#skf.get_n_splits(X, y)

for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
    X_train, X_test = X_scaled[train_index], X_scaled[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

    # Training the model
    svc.fit(X_train, np.ravel(y_train))

    # Prediction on test dataste
    y_pred = svc.predict(X_test)

    # Obtaining the accuracy scores of the model
    score = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
    acc_score.append(score)
print(acc_score)
```

The output of the code (acc_score) looks like below :

```
[1.0, 0.9333333333333333, 1.0, 0.9333333333333333, 0.9333333333333333, 1.0, 0.9333333333333333, 0.9333333333333333, 1.0, 1.0]
```

From this how can I calculate the `standard error` for these accuracy results and `average accuracy` using `NumPy` and `sklearn` in Python ? I wish to print the standard error of these accuracy scores along with the average accuracy

Comment: Please send the code that plots these results so that my help would be more useful

Comment: @gtomer : Have added the code so that it would be more helpful to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the standard error of the mean (or standard error of measurement), [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.sem.html) could be used:

```
import scipy
from scipy import stats
acc_score = [1.0, 0.9333333333333333, 1.0, 0.9333333333333333, 0.9333333333333333, 1.0, 0.9333333333333333, 0.9333333333333333, 1.0, 1.0]
print('ACC std:', '{0:0.2f}'.format(scipy.stats.sem(acc_score)))
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the mean:

```
print ('ACC mean:', '{0:0.2f}'.format(np.mean(acc_score)))
```

To calculate standard error:

```
print ('ACC std:', '{0:0.2f}'.format(np.std(acc_score)))
```

Comment: Thanks ! How can I calculate the standard error for the above accuracy scores ?

Comment: I have added the stdev calculation

Comment: I think np.std calculates std deviation not standard error. Standard error and standard deviation are entirely different